# How can I replace the path value with the parameter passed?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I am trying to pass path parameters in the path in Webhook task body of Palantir foundry in the below format.

```json
{
    "calls": [
        {
            "type": "magritte-rest-call",
            "method": "GET",
            "parameters": {
                "empid": {{json emp}}
            },
           "path": "v1/data/employee/{empid}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting a response in the format below.

```json
"filename=v1_data_employee_null?empid=1234"
```

I am getting `null` in the path parameter `v1_data_employee_null` and value will assigned to query (`?empid=1234`) parameter.

I want path value to be replaced with the parameter passed (`empid`).

Answer (score 0):

Parameters have to be surrounded by `{{` and `}}`. I am also not sure if you really need the `json` in the empid parameter?

```
{
    "calls": [
        {
            "type": "magritte-rest-call",
            "method": "GET",
            "parameters": {
                "empid": "{{empid}}"
            },
           "path": "v1/data/employee/{{empid}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the notation described in the [docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-connection/webhooks-reference/):
`@{createAccount.id}`

```json
      ...
          "recordId": "@{createAccount.id}"
        }
      }
```

In your case, it should work with:
`"path": "v1/data/employee/@{empid}"`

Comment: The question looks more like the legacy webhooks: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-connection/webhooks-reference/#rest-api-legacy